# Is it possible to refresh the chart type in Dash and reuse the existing data, as you can in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Is it possible to reload the chart type and reuse the same data in dash? You can do this in plotly as with the example here [https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/):

```
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=["type", "surface"],
                    label="3D Surface",
                    method="restyle"
                ),
                dict(
                    args=["type", "heatmap"],
                    label="Heatmap",
                    method="restyle"
                )
            ]),
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.1,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ]
)
```

However, I can't find examples or anything in the docs for the same functionality using dash. I've managed to get it to work with some very clunky code (see below). It makes a repeated query for the data that is already there (from postgresql) and it constructs a graph with all the same properties just of a different type. I imagine there's a more elegant way to acheive this! I would appreciate any advice!

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('main-plot', 'figure'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('x_dropdown', 'value'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('y_dropdown', 'value'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('z_dropdown', 'value'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('dimension', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_figure(x, y, z, dimension):
    if dimension == "2D":
        return update_2d_figure(x, y, z)
    else:
        return update_3d_figure(x, y, z)



def update_2d_figure(x, y, z):
    fig = px.scatter(
        data_frame=get_df(select_xyz([x, y, z])),
        x='x',
        y='y',
        color='z',
        hover_data=[
            'name', 'name',
            'nation', 'nation',
        ]
    )
    fig.update_layout(
        width=900,
        height=600,
        autosize=False,
        margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),
        template="plotly_white",
    )
    fig.update_traces(marker_size=5)
    fig.update_scenes(
        aspectratio=dict(x=0.9, y=0.9, z=0.7),
        aspectmode="manual"
    )
    return fig


def update_3d_figure(x, y, z):
    fig = px.scatter_3d(
        data_frame=get_df(select_xyz([x, y, z]),
        x='x',
        y='y',
        z='z',
        color='z',
        hover_data=[
            'name', 'name',
            'nation', 'nation',
        ]
    )
    fig.update_layout(
        width=900,
        height=600,
        autosize=False,
        margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),
        template="plotly_white",
    )
    fig.update_traces(marker_size=5)
    fig.update_scenes(
        aspectratio=dict(x=0.9, y=0.9, z=0.7),
        aspectmode="manual"
    )
    return fig
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to reload the chart type and reuse the same data in Dash using the same `restyle` method that is used in Plotly. You can achieve this by updating the `figure` property of the graph component using an `Input` triggered callback.

You can find more information about updating charts in Dash in the Dash documentation:
https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks#updating-graphs

Answer (score 0):

I used RadioItems to change from 2D to 3D view of scatterplot. Below is my sample code:

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.iris()

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX],suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.RadioItems(
                options=[
                    {"label": "2D", "value": '2D'},
                    {"label": "3D", "value": '3D'}],
                value='2D',
                id="radioitems-input",
                inline=True
            ),
        ],width={'size':2,"offset":0,'order':1},style={'text-align':'right'})
    ]),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Graph(figure={}, id='scatter_plot')
        ])
    ])
])


@app.callback(Output('scatter_plot', 'figure'),
             [Input('radioitems-input', 'value')]) 

def update_pie_chart(radio_itemns):   
    if radio_itemns == '2D':
        fig = px.scatter(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width',color='species')        
        return fig
    if radio_itemns == '3D':              
        fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',color='species')
        return fig
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Hope this help